# VBA Runtime Error 1004 on ActiveSheet.Paste

Tags: excel, vba

This error has been bugging me out for a while now and while running the macros individually, they always work. Since it was a bit of a work to run 10 macros individually, I decided to compile them into one module and can be run on a click of a form button. After doing that, I've been getting this error on the ActiveSheet.Paste for all of the macros. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Sub ItemCode()


'
' AutoFilter Macro
' Scan itemCode
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveSheet.Range("C1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("#DIV/0!", "#N/A", "#Ref", "Null"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
     If Range("C1").End(xlDown).Value = "" Then
    Call CustCode
    Else
Cells.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("SampleFile.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "ItemCode"
    Worksheets("ItemCode").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
 Windows("ABF_Sample.xlsx").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    
    
Application.StatusBar = "20% Completed"


End If
End Sub
```

**Note:** SampleFile.xlsx was declared in another macro.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You will need to change the workbook and sheet names in the code to suit. It's always best to declare your workbooks and sheet names to avoid problems with pasting values in the wrong place. It also means you don't have to activate workbooks and worksheets which really slows down you code.

```
Sub ItemCode()
    
    
    '
    ' AutoFilter Macro
    ' Scan itemCode
    Dim WB1 As Workbook
    Set WB1 = Workbooks("ABF_Sample")
                    
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    
    FilePath = "enter your file path here"
    Filename = "SampleFile"
    
    Dim WB2 As Workbook
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (FilePath & Filename & ".xlsx")
        
    WS1.Range("C1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("#DIV/0!", "#N/A", "#Ref", "Null"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If WS.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Value = "" Then
            Call CustCode
        Else
            WS1.UsedRange.Copy

            With Workbooks(Filename)
                .Sheets.Add.Name = "ItemCode"
                .Sheets("ItemCode").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
                        
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.AutoFilter
        
            Application.StatusBar = "20% Completed"

        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! I run your code however, it said 'Subscript out of range' and it pointed to Set WB2 = Workbooks("SampleFile"). I apologize. I am unfamiliar with VBA and any help is huge for me.

Comment: Is the “SampleFile” workbook open? It must be open otherwise the code will not work.

Comment: SampleFile is a file that would only be created after running the macro. So it doesn't exist before running the code. Is there any way around it?

Comment: I've added some code to create the new workbook for you.

Comment: Hi @jnllmrtzn. If my revised answer has solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.